# Is there anyway to print italic font on ansi console?

Tags: go, console, styles, ansi-escape

Here's the script to color the text and to give bold, blinking, highlighting effect on ansi console.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/mgutz/ansi"
)

color1Func := ansi.ColorFunc(fmt.Sprintf("%v+bh:%v", 181, 255))
color2Func := ansi.ColorFunc(fmt.Sprintf("%v+B:%v", 121, 255))

io.WriteString(os.Stdout, color1Func(text1))
io.WriteString(os.Stdout, color2Func(text2))
```

I tried to print italic font to style better console application, but couldn't find it anywhere for several days of struggling.
Is this something that's not possible with ansi console?

**Update:**

This is what I did checked for `mgutz/ansi` library

```
        if strings.Contains(fgStyle, "b") {
            buf.WriteString(bold)
        }
        if strings.Contains(fgStyle, "B") {
            buf.WriteString(blink)
        }
        if strings.Contains(fgStyle, "u") {
            buf.WriteString(underline)
        }
        if strings.Contains(fgStyle, "i") {
            buf.WriteString(inverse)
        }
        if strings.Contains(fgStyle, "s") {
            buf.WriteString(strikethrough)
        }
        if strings.Contains(fgStyle, "h") {
            base = highIntensityFG
        }
```

It has "i" but it's not italic.

Comment: I don't know who did downvote for my question, but you should just comment something before downvote. This problem is critical for me and I need some discussion at least.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325416/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anyway to print italic font on ansi console?

No.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code:

> Italic    Not widely supported. Sometimes treated as inverse.

This depends so much in the details of your terminal that there is no reliable portable way to do so.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you tell me what can be used to give comment like effect on Ansi console?

Comment: @artgb The only really reliable way is to indicate such stuff via _text_, e.g. quotes or prefixes/suffixes. Relying on color and font in a terminal is very hard.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Do you think this question is meaningless? 2 guys suggested to close but I was trying to find solution for 2 days and got clarification about this.